# Stretching my rotated player forwards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm trying to recreate a movement system to use in my game. It's from a DS game called **Dragon Quest Heroes Rocket Slime** and one of the things players can do is hold down the A button and move in a direction to stretch their slime. Letting go of A while stretched would sling their slime off in the direction they were stretching.

Here's a gif that shows that off:

[image: Desired movement]

I have a bunch of **state** enums for the player (walking, idle, stretching, blasting(after stretching)). When the player is stretching (holding down space while idle) they rotate in the inputted direction but I'm not sure how I would scale the object in that direction.

My player sprite is nested inside an empty game object to allow me to scale it from one side(by offsetting the player and scaling the game object). I rotate the player towards the input direction but I'm not entirely sure how I would scale them forwards in the direction they're facing as it is in the example gif.

```
if (curState == state.stretching)
{
    rBody.velocity = new Vector2(0,0); //so we don't keep our momentum if we try to stretch while walking
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerBody.transform.up, input);
    transform.localScale = ///??

    if (input.magnitude > 0)
    {
        pVelocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(pVelocity + input / 2, 25);
    }
    else
    {
        pVelocity *= new Vector2(2, 2) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm a bit of an idiot.

If I actually looked for more than a second at the axis' of my player when he was rotated, I would've saw that Y was always his facing direction so all I had to do was scale on the y axis.

Fixed code:

```
    if (curState == state.stretching)
    {

        rBody.velocity = new Vector2(0,0); //so we don't keep our momentum if we try to stretch while walking
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerBody.transform.forward, input);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1+pVelocity.magnitude/8,1);
        //we move back as the player scales
        transform.position = orgPos + new Vector3(pVelocity.x/8,pVelocity.y/8,0);

        if (input.magnitude > 0)
        {
            pVelocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(pVelocity + input / 2, 25);

        }
        else
        {
            pVelocity *= new Vector2(2, 2) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
```